# If column has duplicate values then check duplicate in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two column `I` and `N`.

In column I have 6 digit numbers.
In column N have names.

```
   I        N      R(Result)
123456    James    BLANK
123456    Mike     BLANK
111111    Jack     Jack&111111
111111    Jack     Jack&111111
000023    Mike     Blank
000024    James    James&000024
000024    James    James&000024
```

I tried so far but not working

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I:I,I2)>1,IF(OR(N2=N1,I2=I1,I2=I3),CONCATENATE(I2," ",N2),""),"")
```

Comment: Your column R does not make a lot of sense. Can you explain in words a bit more what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(I:I, I2, N:N, N2)>1, I2&" "&N2, "")
```

`COUNTIFS` allows you to enter multiple criteria for the count, as opposed to `COUNTIF`.

Comment: @user206168 Hey, it's just that you don't know all the functions in excel. Even I don't know how all the functions in excel work! ^^;